Partial Redundancy Optimization Not Working
Recently I have been writing a compiler as an exercise. As a guide I have been reading "Compilers Principles Techniques and Tools". I am on chapter 9 page 653 to 654. The end of section 9.5. It goes through the final algorithm for partial Redundancy Elimination
The algorithm consists of 4 passes:

Anticipated Expressions -> Which expressions will be evaluated regardless of path from block X
Available Expressions -> Which expressions are evaluated reguard less of path before block X are evaluated.
Used Expressions -> From point p Which expressions are utilized later down in a program after being evaluated at Point p
Postponable Expressions -> Which blocks can an expression be pushed further down into

Right now I can confirm the Available, Anticipated, and Postponable are working correctly.
The problem is in the Used Expression Analysis or more specifically the building of the Latest set is not working correctly.
As an example I will display my test case that contains this Three Adress Code.
SYMBOL SECTION
DATA SECTION 
 DEF GLOBAL a := 1 <INT>
 DEF GLOBAL b := 2 <INT>
BSS SECTION
CODE SECTION
 DEF i := a IADD b <INT>
 DEF z := a IADD i <INT>
 DEF f := z IADD i <INT>
 IF i LT z
 THEN label1
 ELSE label2
 LABEL label1
 DEF g := z IADD i <INT>
 DEF h := z IADD z <INT>
 GOTO label3
 LABEL label2
 DEF j := z IADD f <INT>
 DEF h := z IADD z <INT>
 GOTO label3
 LABEL label3
 DEF l := z IADD i <INT>
 CALL func([l -> t]<INT>)
END
PROC SECTION

And for the purpose of this example I am analyzing the first Basic Block. Which is:
SYMBOL SECTION
DATA SECTION 
 DEF GLOBAL a := 1 <INT>
 DEF GLOBAL b := 2 <INT>
BSS SECTION
CODE SECTION
 DEF i := a IADD b <INT>
 DEF z := a IADD i <INT>
 DEF f := z IADD i <INT>
 IF i LT z
 THEN label1
 ELSE label2

The instructions say that for the (Latest[B] Intersection Used.Out[B]) add them to the beginning of the block B.
For this Block I got [(z IADD i, INT)] as the Expression
But I can't add that to the beginning of the block because z is calculated in the middle of the block.
This expression seems to make sense for Used.Out because it is also used in a later block. I dont seem to get why it has showed up in my Latest Set. Also why the expressions:
a=1 and b=2 are not in latest.
The other Blocks are as followed
LABEL label1
DEF g := z IADD i <INT>
DEF h := z IADD z <INT>
GOTO label3

and
LABEL label2
DEF j := z IADD f <INT>
DEF h := z IADD z <INT>
GOTO label3

and
LABEL label3
DEF l := z IADD i <INT>
CALL func([l -> t]<INT>)
END
PROC SECTION

And I assume the connections between the blocks are obvious???
